# Framework on top of iOS Cocoa touch / SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

Are there any frameworks available for use on top of the iOS Cocoa Touch, to reduce boilerplate code and increase the development speed? Similar to how PHP has Codeignitor, Ruby has Rails, Python has Django.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa Touch itself is already a very high level framework, it's not that neccessary to build another one on top of it, given the amount of customizations often required by a specific mobile app.

However in terms of "increasing development speed", there are **plenty** of components (see [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)) that you can use in your project. Sometimes you can find a host of components in one project, for example flat UI controls.

Answer (score 0):

Github is full of them for specific purposes (example, [RestKit wraps lots of standard HTTP and CoreData methods](https://github.com/restkit/restkit)), and many developers will collect a number of their own personal favorites to incorporate in all their projects, commonly making use of Macro's and "helper" classes.

The problem with Macro's and helper classes though, is that they usually make your code less readable, maintainable, and much harder to transfer to other dev's

And while there is plenty of room for rational people to hold different opinions here, I'd offer the following thoughts:

- You are very "close to the metal" not just with the chips, but a slew of sensors and sensor inputs as well. You'll change a displayed color one minute, and the next you'll be sampling raw bit-stream data from a microphone and syncing it up with a series of raw image data buffers. Part of why iOS is so verbose, is that it handles an extremely wide range of tasks.
- You don't have to shorten long statements to develop quickly. Cut and paste (or yank & pull, or whatever emacs does) can easily re-use pieces from a well maintained "cheat-sheet" that you put together.